# Limit of stationary distribution (or invariant measure)

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence, ergodic-theory, stationary-processes

$\{X_{i}(\Delta )\}_{i=1}^{\infty }$ is an ergodic process with state space $%
\mathbb{R}$, and $X_{i}(\Delta )$ depends on a parameter $\Delta \in (0,1]$.
$X_{i}(\Delta )$ has a unique stationary distribution $\pi _{\Delta }$,
which also depends on $\Delta $.

Given a smooth and bounded function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$. For any integer $%
n\geq 1$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, and $\forall\Delta >0$, we define
\begin{equation*}
F_{n}(\Delta ):=\mathbb{E[}f(X_{n}(\Delta ))|X_{0}(\Delta )=x],
\end{equation*}
and define
\begin{equation*}
F(\Delta ):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\pi _{\Delta }(dx).
\end{equation*}
**Now suppose that:**

(1) for any $n\geq 1$, $F_{n}(\Delta )$ is a smooth function for $\Delta \in
(0,1]$.

(2) for any integer $k\geq 0$,
\begin{equation*}
\text{the limit }\lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0}\frac{d^{k}F_{n}(\Delta )}{%
d\Delta ^{k}}\text{ exists.}
\end{equation*}

(3) (geometric ergodicity) there exists $\alpha >0$ such that, for any $n\geq 1$ and $\Delta >0$,
\begin{equation*}
\left\vert F_{n}(\Delta )-F(\Delta )\right\vert <\exp (-\alpha n\Delta ).
\end{equation*}

***The Question is to prove:***
\begin{equation*}
\text{the limit }\lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0}F(\Delta )\text{ exists.}
\end{equation*}

**My idea:** for any $\Delta >0$, by ergodic theorem we have
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }F_{n}(\Delta )=F(\Delta ),
\end{equation*}
but this convergence is pointwise for $\Delta >0$. However, it is still hard
to say something about the limit $\lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0}F(\Delta )$.

Also, the condition (1) implies that, for any $n\geq 1$, $F_{n}(\Delta )$ can be extended to $%
\Delta =0$, i.e., there exists a smooth function $\bar{F}_{n}(\Delta )$ on $%
[0,\Delta ]$ such that $\bar{F}_{n}(\Delta )=F_{n}(\Delta )$ for any $\Delta
\in (0,1]$.